# Convergence of sum using ratio test

Tags: sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence

Determine the values of x ∈ R for which the following series converge:

$\sum_1^\infty \frac{x^nn^n}{n!}$

My attempt: I used the ratio test to obtain $|x|< \frac{1}{e}$ as the interval where it convergences for sure, but I am unable to determine whether the series convergences at $x=\frac{1}{e}$ and $x=\frac{-1}{e}$ (when the limit of the ratio is $1$ and the test is inconclusive).

Comment: Try Stirling's formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the cases $x=\pm \frac 1 e$ we can use Stirling  approximation

$$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$

Comment: So, that gives me that at x=1/e, series diverges by p-test and at x=-1/e, it converges by alternating series test. Is this correct?

Comment: @childishsadbino That's absolutely correct indeed!